# Wanted to customize the python argparse module generated errors

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

```
import argparse    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-f", "--filepath", help="Input the file path")
group.add_argument("-d", "--dirpath", help="Input the directory path")
```

For Example if I use both options -f and -d,I'm getting the following error,which is generated by python:
error: argument -d/--dirpath: expected one argument

But I want to customise the error and it should be defined by me.

Comment: @Martijin I get the following if I use -f and -d at a time ..** error: argument -d/--dirpath: expected one argument** and here my intension is to customise the error.

Comment: You are getting the correct error for those switches, they both require a single value each. `bin/python test.py -f foo -d bar` gives you *error: argument -d/--dirpath: not allowed with argument -f/--filepath*.

Comment: @Martjin-I am aware of error but here my question is to change the error which is displayed in stdout. like error: argument -d/--dirpath: please pass only one option,either with -f or -d

Comment: it should be customised error..and  be able to change it by the programmer.

Comment: You'll have to look elsewhere, argparse doesn't let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
2140:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552334.py
Namespace(dirpath=None, filepath=None)
```

These are all produced when there's a mismatch between the Action `nargs` and available strings.  While message format is the same, it is customized to the argument's name:

```
2140:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552334.py -f
usage: stack50552334.py [-h] [-f FILEPATH | -d DIRPATH]
stack50552334.py: error: argument -f/--filepath: expected one argument
2140:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552334.py -d
usage: stack50552334.py [-h] [-f FILEPATH | -d DIRPATH]
stack50552334.py: error: argument -d/--dirpath: expected one argument
2140:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552334.py -f -d
usage: stack50552334.py [-h] [-f FILEPATH | -d DIRPATH]
stack50552334.py: error: argument -f/--filepath: expected one argument
2141:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552334.py -f foo -d
usage: stack50552334.py [-h] [-f FILEPATH | -d DIRPATH]
stack50552334.py: error: argument -d/--dirpath: expected one argument
```

But when both flags are provided with the expected arguments, then the `mutually_exclusive_group` test comes into play, and raises its own error.

```
2141:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552334.py -f foo -d dir
usage: stack50552334.py [-h] [-f FILEPATH | -d DIRPATH]
stack50552334.py: error: argument -d/--dirpath: not allowed with argument -f/--filepath
```

The first class of message is produced in:

```
def _match_argument(self, action, arg_strings_pattern):
    # match the pattern for this action to the arg strings
    nargs_pattern = self._get_nargs_pattern(action)
    match = _re.match(nargs_pattern, arg_strings_pattern)

    # raise an exception if we weren't able to find a match
    if match is None:
        nargs_errors = {
            None: _('expected one argument'),
            OPTIONAL: _('expected at most one argument'),
            ONE_OR_MORE: _('expected at least one argument'),
        }
        default = ngettext('expected %s argument',
                           'expected %s arguments',
                           action.nargs) % action.nargs
        msg = nargs_errors.get(action.nargs, default)
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg)

    # return the number of arguments matched
    return len(match.group(1))
```

The `_` is alias for `gettext.gettext`.  So there is a possibility of customizing the messages with this mechanism.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html

```
from gettext import gettext as _, ngettext
```

I don't have any experience with this multlingual localization.

The `mutually_exclusive` error is raised in:

```
    def take_action(action, argument_strings, option_string=None):
        ...
        # error if this argument is not allowed with other previously
        # seen arguments, assuming that actions that use the default
        # value don't really count as "present"
        if argument_values is not action.default:
            seen_non_default_actions.add(action)
            for conflict_action in action_conflicts.get(action, []):
                if conflict_action in seen_non_default_actions:
                    msg = _('not allowed with argument %s')
                    action_name = _get_action_name(conflict_action)
                    raise ArgumentError(action, msg % action_name)
```

Again, there is the possibility of `gettext` customization.

### custom argparse.py

Of course there's nothing preventing you from modifying a copy of `argparse.py` file, and placing in your own directory so it is loaded instead of the default one.

### post parsing testing

If the wording of the `mutually_exclusive` error is bothering you (as opposed to the `expected one argument` errors, you could omit that group from the parser, and do your own tests after parsing.  If the user provides non-default values for both `args.filepath` and `args.dirpath` call `parser.error('your own message')`, or raise your own error.